# Parse image from XML file with jsoup

Tags: android, xml, android-listview, jsoup, android-imageview

I have this xml structure:

```
<item>
   <guid</guid>
   <title</title>
   <link></link>
   <description><![CDATA[<img src="https://www.somesite.com/someimage1.jpg" />]]></description>
   <pubDate></pubDate>
   <author></author>
   <dc:creator></dc:creator>
</item>

<item>
   <guid</guid>
   <title</title>
   <link></link>
   <description><![CDATA[<img src="https://www.somesite.com/someimage2.jpg" />]]></description>
   <pubDate></pubDate>
   <author></author>
   <dc:creator></dc:creator>
</item>
```

how to parse this with jsoup, to retrive the image and use it to popolate listview adapter?

Comment: with xmlpullparser how to parse it? can you helpme?

Comment: This can be done with Jsoup aswell. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Kosma first look at the docs. give a try then if you don't get come back and update your question with what you tried

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
String html = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"><root><item><guid></guid><title></title><link></link><description><![CDATA[<img src=\"https://www.somesite.com/someimage1.jpg\" />]]></description><pubDate></pubDate><author></author><creator></creator></item><item><guid></guid><title></title><link></link><description><![CDATA[<img src=\"https://www.somesite.com/someimage2.jpg\" />]]></description><pubDate></pubDate><author></author><creator></creator></item></root>";
                Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());
                for (Element e : doc.select("description")) {
                    System.out.println(e.text());
                }
```

You can add the string to an Array or listview adapter

Answer (score 0):

Use this library for parsing image https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper .
Usage is very simple like https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper#usage.